# Python, mmap, what if I don't call mmap.close() manually?

Tags: python, mmap

I came from the C++/RAII world.

So it seems confused to me on when and how to call mmap.close() 
[not file.close()].

Or, not calling it at all? Would there be a leak?

As for the sample code from the [document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) ;
what if I want to use the mmap buffer outside currrent module,
and not close it in-place at the last line?

```
    import mmap

    # write a simple example file
    with open("hello.txt", "wb") as f:
        f.write("Hello Python!\n")

    with open("hello.txt", "r+b") as f:
        # memory-map the file, size 0 means whole file
        mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
        # read content via standard file methods
        print mm.readline()  # prints "Hello Python!"
        # read content via slice notation
        print mm[:5]  # prints "Hello"
        # update content using slice notation;
        # note that new content must have same size
        mm[6:] = " world!\n"
        # ... and read again using standard file methods
        mm.seek(0)
        print mm.readline()  # prints "Hello  world!"
        # close the map
        mm.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the [mmapmodule.c source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/mmapmodule.c), the file is unmapped and closed when the object reference count goes to zero and it is deleted. The following function is in the object's `tp_dealloc`. This is similar to the `close` method also in the source and it means that all you have to do is exit the scope of any variable referring to the map or `del` them.

There is a caveat to all of this. If you have circular references that the python garbage collector can't resolve, the reference count will never go to zero and the resources won't be cleaned up. Mind those back references!

Second caveat - I'm referring to CPython. Who knows what lurks in the heart of other implementations.

```
static void
mmap_object_dealloc(mmap_object *m_obj)
{
#ifdef MS_WINDOWS
    if (m_obj->data != NULL)
        UnmapViewOfFile (m_obj->data);
    if (m_obj->map_handle != NULL)
        CloseHandle (m_obj->map_handle);
    if (m_obj->file_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        CloseHandle (m_obj->file_handle);
    if (m_obj->tagname)
        PyMem_Free(m_obj->tagname);
#endif /* MS_WINDOWS */

#ifdef UNIX
    if (m_obj->fd >= 0)
        (void) close(m_obj->fd);
    if (m_obj->data!=NULL) {
        munmap(m_obj->data, m_obj->size);
    }
#endif /* UNIX */

    if (m_obj->weakreflist != NULL)
        PyObject_ClearWeakRefs((PyObject *) m_obj);
    Py_TYPE(m_obj)->tp_free((PyObject*)m_obj);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the timely response!